# not able to ease in whole container on click again

Tags: javascript, css, easeinout

I have a problem with my code:

While I try to make the code to ease-in again the whole container to the base state, it only closes the subsections, not the whole section to the basic state, maybe you will be able to see where is the mistake in my code

whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .kontener {
            background-color: orange;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 5px;
            width: 300px;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
        }

        .poziom-1 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .poziom-2 {
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .linia-pozioma {
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid #333;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        .kontener.rozwiniete .poziom-2 {
            max-height: 1000px; /* Dostosuj maksymalną wysokość */
        }

        .kontener.rozwiniete .poziom-1 .znak-rozwijania {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        .znak-rozwijania {
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        .grafika-rozwijania {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="kontener">
        <div class="poziom-1" onclick="toggleRozwijanie(this)">
            Główny tekst 1
            <span class="grafika-rozwijania">&#9654;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="poziom-2">
            <div class="kontener">
                <div class="linia-pozioma"></div>
                <div class="poziom-1" onclick="toggleRozwijanie(this)">
                    Podpunkt 1
                    <span class="znak-rozwijania"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>
                    <span class="grafika-rozwijania">&#9654;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="poziom-2">
                    - Pod-podpunkt 1<br>
                    - Pod-podpunkt 2<br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="kontener">
                <div class="linia-pozioma"></div>
                <div class="poziom-1" onclick="toggleRozwijanie(this)">
                    Podpunkt 2
                    <span class="znak-rozwijania"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>
                    <span class="grafika-rozwijania">&#9654;</span>
                </div>
                <div class="poziom-2">
                    - Pod-podpunkt 3<br>
                    - Pod-podpunkt 4<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Dodaj pozostałe kontenery tu -->

    <script>
        function toggleRozwijanie(element) {
            const kontenerGlowny = element.closest(".kontener");
            const poziom2 = element.nextElementSibling;
            const ikonaRozwijania = element.querySelector(".znak-rozwijania i");
            const grafikaRozwijania = element.querySelector(".grafika-rozwijania");

            if (kontenerGlowny.classList.contains("rozwiniete")) {
                poziom2.style.maxHeight = null;
                ikonaRozwijania.classList.remove("fa-caret-down");
                ikonaRozwijania.classList.add("fa-caret-right");
                grafikaRozwijania.textContent = "\u25B6"; // Zmiana na strzałkę w prawo
                kontenerGlowny.classList.remove("rozwiniete");
            } else {
                // Zwijanie innych otwartych kontenerów
                const otwarteKontenery = document.querySelectorAll(".kontener.rozwiniete");
                otwarteKontenery.forEach((kontener) => {
                    const poziomy2 = kontener.querySelectorAll(".poziom-2");
                    poziomy2.forEach((poziom) => {
                        poziom.style.maxHeight = null;
                    });
                    const ikonyRozwijania = kontener.querySelectorAll(".znak-rozwijania i");
                    ikonyRozwijania.forEach((ikona) => {
                        ikona.classList.remove("fa-caret-down");
                        ikona.classList.add("fa-caret-right");
                    });
                    const grafikiRozwijania = kontener.querySelectorAll(".grafika-rozwijania");
                    grafikiRozwijania.forEach((grafika) => {
                        grafika.textContent = "\u25B6";
                    });
                    kontener.classList.remove("rozwiniete");
                });

                const wszystkiePodpunkty = kontenerGlowny.querySelectorAll(".poziom-2");
                const wysokoscPodpunktow = Array.from(wszystkiePodpunkty).reduce((sum, podpunkt) => {
                    return sum + podpunkt.scrollHeight;
                }, 0);

                poziom2.style.maxHeight = wysokoscPodpunktow + "px";
                ikonaRozwijania.classList.remove("fa-caret-right");
                ikonaRozwijania.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
                grafikaRozwijania.textContent = "\u25BC"; // Zmiana na strzałkę w dół
                kontenerGlowny.classList.add("rozwiniete");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```